# How do i get only the LocalUser path?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this line:

```
outputtext = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\outputtext";
```

This line contain:

"C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\outputtext"

I want it to contain only:

C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) static class

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

The enum [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) offers various predefined locations that you can use as a base directory to store your data. Another possibility is the `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`. The difference between the two enums is the following:

> **LocalApplicationData** The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by the current,
>   non-roaming user.
>
> **ApplicationData** The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.

Do not forget that these locations are shared by every application installed on your system. So it is a good practice to create a subfolder just for your application and store your data inside it. Something like this

```
string commonFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string appDataFolder = Path.Combine(commonFolder,"Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen"); 
if(!Directory.Exists(appDataFolder))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataFolder);

string dataFile = Path.Combine(appDataFolder,"outputData.txt");
........
```

Comment: To match his code you should be using the `LocalApplicationData` special folder, your code will give him `C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Remote`

Comment: Yes, @ScottChamberlain you are right if he has a roaming environment. I will add your comment to the answer